# How to upload an image in database and folder using Ajax in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to upload an image by **ajax** in **Codeigniter** or **PHP** but it does not.Please help me. Tell me all code with **HTML**,**JQUERY** and Target page.

Comment: what do you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:

https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload

Another is here:

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/